# Cannot convert return expression of type 'Array<AboutMe>' to return type '[About me]'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a data model like this

```
struct Aboutme {
    private(set) public var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

And a data service like this

```
struct DataService {
    static let instance = DataService()

    private let sections = [
        [Aboutme(name: "Rate App on the App store")],
        [Aboutme(name: "Facebook")],
        [Aboutme(name: "Twitter")],
        [Aboutme(name: "Linkeden")],
        [Aboutme(name: "Instagram")],
        [Aboutme(name: "Email Feedback")]
                            ]

    func getSections() -> [Aboutme] {
        return sections
    }
}
```

However wen i try to return the sections of type About me, it won't let me, says i can't convert the return expression to another one. How can i fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sections` is (implicitly) declared as `[[Aboutme]]` the return value of `getSections()` is `[Aboutme]` that's is classic type mismatch.

Solutions:

1. Change the body of `sections`

   ```
   struct DataService {
       static let instance = DataService()

       private let sections = [
           Aboutme(name: "Rate App on the App store"),
           Aboutme(name: "Facebook"),
           Aboutme(name: "Twitter"),
           Aboutme(name: "Linkeden"),
           Aboutme(name: "Instagram"),
           Aboutme(name: "Email Feedback")
                           ]

       func getSections() -> [Aboutme] {
           return sections
       }
   }
   ```
2. Change the return type of `getSections()`

   ```
   struct DataService {
       static let instance = DataService()

       private let sections = [
           [Aboutme(name: "Rate App on the App store")],
           [Aboutme(name: "Facebook")],
           [Aboutme(name: "Twitter")],
           [Aboutme(name: "Linkeden")],
           [Aboutme(name: "Instagram")],
           [Aboutme(name: "Email Feedback")]
                               ]

       func getSections() -> [[Aboutme]] {
           return sections
       }
   }
   ```

As `sections` is a constant anyway the function `getSections()` is redundant and not needed at all.

---

And why not simply

```
struct Aboutme {
    let name: String
}
```

?

You get the initializer for free and `name` is the intended constant.

Comment: i'm gonna call it in the number of rows in sections method to display the data in sections in the tableview. Works now. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your `sections` follows the collection of arrays so you need to go with return type array of array to return all `[Aboutme]` objects.

```
func getSections() -> [[Aboutme]] {
    return sections
}
```

Comment: Works now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the return type of `getSections` method and variable `sections` are different type. You have to change the var `sections` type as like `getSections` method return type or `getSections` return type like `sections`.

So your can do this:

```
 struct DataService {
            static let instance = DataService()

            private let sections = [
                Aboutme(name: "Rate App on the App store"),
                Aboutme(name: "Facebook"),
                Aboutme(name: "Twitter"),
                Aboutme(name: "Linkeden"),
                Aboutme(name: "Instagram"),
                Aboutme(name: "Email Feedback")
        ]


            func getSections() -> [Aboutme] {
                return sections
            }
        }
```

Or like this:

```
struct DataService {
            static let instance = DataService()

            private let sections = [
                [Aboutme(name: "Rate App on the App store")],
                [Aboutme(name: "Facebook")],
                [Aboutme(name: "Twitter")],
                [Aboutme(name: "Linkeden")],
                [Aboutme(name: "Instagram")],
                [Aboutme(name: "Email Feedback")]
        ]


            func getSections() -> [[Aboutme]] {
                return sections
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sections declaration is wrong. You declare sections as an array of arrays (type is `Array<Array<Section>>`), so of course that can't be converted to `Array<Section>`.

```
struct DataService {
    static let instance = DataService()

    private let sections = [
        Aboutme(name: "Rate App on the App store"),
        Aboutme(name: "Facebook"),
        Aboutme(name: "Twitter"),
        Aboutme(name: "Linkeden"),
        Aboutme(name: "Instagram"),
        Aboutme(name: "Email Feedback")
                            ]

    func getSections() -> [Aboutme] {
        return sections
    }
}
```